# Динамическая загрузка javascript кода

Tags: javascript, html, dom

В html имеем следующий код:

```
<head>
    <script id="cont_js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

В определенный момент динамически загружается javascript код:

```
document.getElementById('cont_js').textContent = response;
```

Код работает, функции выполняются.
Но, если попытаться загрузить другой код тем же способом, в тот же элемент `id="cont_js"`, то новый код не работает. Т.е. визуально в инспекторе элемент `id="cont_js"` содержит новый код, но фактически там код, загруженный в первый раз (выполняется через консоль).
Такое впечатление, что необходимо какое дополнительное действие для обновления содержимого.

Подскажите как исправить?

Comment: Проще создавать новый тег script и добавлять его в html

Comment: @Alexey Ten, да, так заработало.